"There is one of him sharing a private joke with his dad that he loves so much, . . . "
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 19)

(William, the chorister, musing about his dad's funeral)

The best memories a vicar wouldn't know about, and anyway, William's not sure what a best memory is; they are all a muddle of good and bad, warm and cold. There is one of him sharing a private joke with his dad that he loves so much, it's worth enduring the not so nice sequence of events that led up to it.
I take "one" in "There is one of him" to mean "memory". The subject of "sharing a private joke with his dad" is "one"(memory) and "one"(memory) is sharing a joke with his dad. I know what "share a joke" means and what "share something with someone" means. My problem is, how can a memory share a joke with William's dead father? It seems to me the prep "with" doesn't belong to "share" but to "joke" in this context, right?

There is [a memory] of {him sharing a joke with his dad}. "Him sharing a joke with his dad" is what the memory is about.

'A memory is' can be equivalent to 'a memory consists of'. One of my favourite memories is the arrival of a pet cat to our house when I was aged ten.

Obviously if William is reminiscing about the time when he and his dad shared a private joke, his dad wasn't dead at the time! I can't for the life of me see how you manage to parse the text to end up with the bizarre idea that the father was dead within the context of the joke. Obviously that's a nonsense interpretation, but I can't see anything unclear about the text.

@MichaelHarvey: I've no doubt your dear cat is now well and truly an ex- cat. Pushing up the daisies, as is William's dead father.

@FumbleFingers - Millie (named after Millicent Martin, the singer on the TV show That Was the Week that Was) arrived in spring 1963 and lived to be 18. A very pretty 'calico cat'.

Obviously memories in the context of a funeral are of the deceased when they were alive!

@FumbleFingers - Millie didn't get tired and shagged out after a prolonged meow.

@ FumbleFingers - "I can't for the life of me see how you manage to parse the text to end up with the bizarre idea that the father was dead within the context of the joke." - The problem there is that the main clause "There is one" and the non-finite clause "him sharing a private joke with his dad" have different subjects - main clause: "one"; subordinated non-finite clause: (him) respectively "he"/"William" as "ishtar" are saying rightly in their answer. That isn't the case very often and I didn't think of this possibility, I'm afraid.
